# Cannot create freeStyleJob jobs in a loop - No signature of method: script.freeStyleJob() is applicable for argument types: Integer, Closure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create many Jenkins jobs for many branches given in the bitbucket repo.
So, for the moment I developed a groovy script that retrieves all branches.
Note that I am using the **Use the provided DSL script**, to do that :

```
def project = "Test-Jobs"
def command = "git ls-remote -h $GIT_URL"

def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()             

// trouver toutes les branches

def branches = proc.in.text.readLines().collect { 
    it.replaceAll(/[a-z0-9]*\trefs\/heads\//, '') 
}

println branches
```

This return :

```
[feature/655, feature/BPDC-655, master, release/1.0.0, release/1.2.0, release/2.4.0]
```

Then, I tried to create a name job for each branch using this code :

```
def jobNames = branches.collect { it + "_test" }
println jobNames
```

This was fine also. But, my problem was about creating **freeStyleJob** for each branch :

```
for (ii = 0; ii < jobNames.size(); ii++)
{    
    
  freeStyleJob(ii) {
    logRotator(-1, 10)
    steps {
        shell ("echo first programm")
    }
        }
    }
```

But this does not work at all. And, I get this error :

> ERROR: (script, line 26) No signature of method: script.freeStyleJob()
> is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer,
> script$_run_closure3) values: [0, script$_run_closure3@4e08608d]
> Possible solutions: freeStyleJob(java.lang.String),
> freeStyleJob(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure) Finished: FAILURE

In fact, I tried many times to iterate through the jobNames list object, but I got usually errors. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [freeStyleJob](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob) block requires a String variable. `ii` keeps an integer. You have to convert it to String. Few options:

```
freeStyleJob(ii as String) {
```

```
freeStyleJob(Integer.toString(ii)) {
```

```
freeStyleJob("${ii}") {
```